# Issue when I display Powerpoint on my form in c#.net

Tags: c#

Actullay I want powerpoint must be open and display on my Form itself.and I don't want to open powerpoint in microsoft...so I have done what I want,means powerpoint is opening in my Own form itself. But issue is that at runtime powerpoint open on form, at the same time one other instance of powerpoint is opening and I don't want that other one. So how to remove that other instance of powerpoint?
please check code.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ppt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, String lpString);

    ppt.Presentation presentation;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowView oSlideShowView;
    bool flag = false;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void open(string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            ppt.Application application;

            // For Display in Panel
            IntPtr screenClasshWnd = (IntPtr)0;
            IntPtr x = (IntPtr)0;

            application = new ppt.Application();

            presentation = application.Presentations.Open(FileName, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            panel1.Controls.Add(application as Control);
            ppt.SlideShowSettings sst1 = presentation.SlideShowSettings;

            sst1.LoopUntilStopped = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

            ppt.Slides objSlides = presentation.Slides;

            sst1.LoopUntilStopped = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

            sst1.StartingSlide = 1;
            sst1.EndingSlide = objSlides.Count;

            panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            sst1.ShowType = ppt.PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeKiosk;

            ppt.SlideShowWindow sw = sst1.Run();
            //sw=Objssws
            oSlideShowView = presentation.SlideShowWindow.View;

            IntPtr pptptr = (IntPtr)sw.HWND;
            SetParent(pptptr, panel1.Handle);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
       // openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        //string FileName = "C:\\Task\\Welcome to PowerPoint.ppt";
        open(openFileDialog.FileName);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oSlideShowView.Next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy smokes man -- take some time to properly ask a question.  How can you expect people on this site to take time to answer questions that you didn't take the time to ask?

Comment: Indeed, I've read your question twice and it's still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `application.Visible = false`

Comment: Thanx for reply..but steel it open other instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply replace the following line**

presentation = application.Presentations.Open(FileName, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

**with the following code line:**
presentation = application.Presentations.Open(FileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);